# GLFW 3: How to get delta of the mouse scroll wheel with ScrollCallback (LWJGL 3)

Tags: opengl, callback, lwjgl, glfw

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoxDDZmctnU&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=19) on 3D game development with LWJGL and OpenGL. And in the series, the instructor is using LWJGL 2 while I'm using LWJGL 3 with GLFW. And in a certain section he uses LWJGL's input implementations only available in LWJGL 2, so I am forced to use GLFW's callback system. I was able to add input functionality for key input, cursor movement, and mouse button input, but when I tried to add a scrolling callback, it seemed that the offsets only return -1 and 1 for the scrolling directions, and when added, the (3rd person) camera translated forward and backwards indefinitely, and the intention was for every scroll movement the camera translates forward or backward a certain distance. In actuality I was expecting to get delta values for each scrolling movement. Previously I was messing around trying to see if I could set the offset values for an amount of delay time then set them back to 0 but to no avail. I tried searching for an answer, but I found nothing related to my problem. I may be stupid, but here's the code.

MouseScroll callback class:

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWScrollCallback;

    public class MouseScroll extends GLFWScrollCallback {

        private static float XScroll;
        private static float YScroll;
        private static float DXScroll;
        private static float DYScroll;

        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, double xoffset, double yoffset) {
            XScroll = (float) xoffset;
            YScroll = (float) yoffset;
            // Don't know how to achieve this here
        }

        /* Returns raw offset values */
        public float getXScroll() {
            return XScroll;
        }

        public float getYScroll() {
            return YScroll;
        }

        /* Returns the rate of each scrolling movement */
        public float getDXScroll() {
            return DXScroll;
        }

        public float getDYScroll() {
            return DYScroll;
        }

    }
```

Method for getting YScroll in Input class:

```
public static float getMouseYScroll() {
    return mouseScroll.getYScroll(); // mouseScroll is reference to MouseScroll callback
}
```

Method using the callback in Camera.java:

```
private void calculateZoom() {
        float zoomLevel =  Input.getMouseYScroll() * 0.1f;
        distanceFromPlayer -= zoomLevel;
    }
```

Update method in Camera.java:

```
public void move() {
        calculateZoom();
        calculatePitch();
        calculateAngleAroundPlayer();
        float horizontalDistance = calculateHorizontalDistance();
        float verticalDistance = calculateVerticalDistance();
        calculateCameraPosition(horizontalDistance, verticalDistance);
        this.yaw = 180 - (player.getRotY() + angleAroundPlayer);
    }
```

And finally there is `camera.move()` that gets called every loop iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLFWScrollCallback is invoked whenever the user generates some scroll operation (up por down or even left or right). As a result, you will set `XScroll` / `YScroll` to `-1` or `1` **and leave it as such** until the next scroll event happens. You need to implement some way to reset it to zero. Potentially you could do something like

```
    public float getYScroll() {
        float value = YScroll;
        YScroll = 0.0f;
        return value;
    }
```

but this will only work if you call `getYScroll` only once per frame. It is not exactly clear how you want to deal with such events (i.e. do you want to store them until consumed - potentially not every frame), but most likely you get away by simply adding some reset method to `MouseScroll` which you call at the end of every frame - since you query the scroll wheel every frame, no event will be lost.

Comment: I just realized my stupidity, I was doing the exact same thing with my other callbacks and never realized that I could do the same. Thanks.